# Optimizing like '%text%' condition without removing it

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I need to optimize query although I don't have access to application source code. 
Simplified query goes like this:

```
select from eu.myview where name like '%text%'
```

Until now I was solving this by generating full text index and replacing like with contains condition. That worked fine. However, in this case I don't have access to application source code and I can't remove like condition. I have access to database and I can change eu.myview source.
Is there anything I can do to optimize this query?

Comment: How exactly is the script called and the condition passed to the query?

Comment: Your first `'%'` (at the start) is the most costly one.

Comment: @mellamokb I don't really know since I don't have access to app source code.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The leading % invalidates use of index *seeks* so every row must be examined... whether via an index or table *scan*

Comment: Is there a way to get text in like condition and use it in other condition inside same query? I would take '%text%' and use it in Contains condition inside view. Could that Contains condition narrow down search set so like condition operates on smaller set of data? I don't know how sql server handles that situation and this sounds like SF but I rather ask than miss something.